# Process incoming email on IMail with independent executable

Tags: email

I have an application that I need to implement that parses email content into a database. Parsing the email is not a problem. What I need is a trigger for the incoming mail to my IMail 11 server.

What options are available in IMail outside of monitoring the mailbox contents via POP3 or IMAP? Is there way to get notification of the file similar to the old file store event on Exhange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found it and implemented it.

Create an alias of type program. "Resolves To" should be set to the exe for processing the individual emails. (This is where a developer's hard work comes in. If anyone is looking for help here let me know.) This exe must except a single argument which will be the name of the physical email file from the spool.

Here is a sample of the configuration. The below setups up all email to a domain to be processed by an exe:

[image]